# ffplay using -autoexit in combination with -t - very slow exit

Tags: ffmpeg

I need a way to validate a library of videos (almost all H264/MP4 and some WEBM) - just at a "Does it play or does it not play" level. These videos are a on Windows 10 system acting as a server - all on a 1Gbit LAN. My thought was to use a PowerShell script to create a list of video files to be checked and then a foreach loop inside which I invoke ffplay like:

`ffplay -loglevel error -autoexit -t 5 filename.mp4 2> logfile.txt`

which works fine but the problem is that when the stop point is reached the playback stops, but video window doesn't close for anything up to 30 seconds, which will enormously elongate my testing time for these many 100s videos. Interestingly, when the video window is in that frozen state, if I press "Q" in the window it closes immediately.

I tried it without the stderr redirection and with no loglevel set - same problem. I don't think this is due to launching it from PowerShell as I tried it from a DOS command line too and same thing. Also tried it on a different system and using different video etc. Always the same.

Seems to me that maybe autoexit doesn't check very often if the video end has been reached? I think that even though the video has stopped, the file is still being read from disk until some point (an i-frame maybe) is reached? If I use the same video twice in a row, the exit is almost immediate - suggesting perhaps fast-reading of already cached data? But of course, that is no help to me because in my testing each video is read only once.

Is there a better way to do this, or a better option I could use?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're doing this in such a way that you're going to be actually watching a bit of each to see if it works, why not throw them into VLC in batches & just keep tapping `N` every few seconds? If there's an error, it will spring a dialog & let you know.

Comment: No, sadly I need this to run unattended. By my reckoning it could take days.

Comment: You don't need to actually play them. Just test decoding: `ffmpeg -max_error_rate 0.01 -i filename -f null - ` Then check `%ERRORLEVEL%` for non-zero code.